# Python - AndroidViewClient take snapshots in high FPS

Tags: android, python-2.7, androidviewclient

I wanted to take snapshots of my device in 60 FPS using AndroidViewClient on Python, so I used the function `device.takeSnapshot(reconnect=True)` in a loop to do so. However, it appeared that the time consumption of this function is around 0.5 seconds which gives me 2 FPS. I think the re-connection is what it makes it long. So why the device disconnects automatically after taking one snapshot? Is there a way to keep the connection on? Is there any other way to improve time consumption and get higher FPS?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)'s objective to be a `screenrecord`er,  I ran a test like this

```
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
t = time.time()
for s in range(60):
    device.takeSnapshot(reconnect=True)
t1 = time.time()-t
print "t={} secs  r={} screenshots/sec".format(t1, 60/t1)
```

and on a fast phone (Pixel 3) it can take 60 screenshots in 15 secs or **4 FPS**.
Also, take into account that the screen size is 1080x2160 so there's a lot of bytes to transfer.

You can take a look at `takeSnapshot()` source code and see that there are some parts you can remove or change if you want to speed it up, like the PIL `Image` creation that could be deferred.